# Determine if one point set is a rotation of another

Tags: geometry, algorithms, euclidean-geometry, rotations, spheres

Suppose I have two finite sets $X, Y$ each consisting of $n$ points lying on the $d$-dimensional unit sphere $S^d \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$. What is an efficient algorithm to determine if $X$ is a rotation of $Y$, i.e., if there exists $R \in \mathrm{SO}_{d+1}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $X = RY$?

The relation "$X$ is a rotation of $Y$" is an equivalence relation, so one obvious approach is to devise an efficiently-computable function taking each $n$-point subset of $S^d$ to a fixed representative of its equivalence class. Then, one can simply check if $X$ and $Y$ map to the same representative. However, the point sets that arise in my application tend to be highly symmetric (think of the vertices of a cube or icosahedron), so ideas along the lines of "send the nearest pair of points to the equator..." tend to be ineffective.

Comment: Can you compute the automorphism groups of $X$ and $Y$, i.e. all rotations that map each set into itself? As you mentioned your sets to be highly symmetric, this might be an option. If $X$ and $Y$ are rotation-equivalent, these groups have to be conjugated.

Comment: @DirkLiebhold I've considered it, but I don't think automorphism groups would be effective. For one thing, automorphism groups can get exponentially big (the automorphism group of the $n$-dimensional octahedron has $2^n n!$ elements), but even if I had an efficient way to compute a presentation or generating set, they would still fail to distinguish many of my sets, a significant proportion of which have only trivial or $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry.

Comment: You can write down quite a lot of restrictions on $R$, if you not only look at the points but other things left invariant by a rotation (e.g. distance between points, angles, etc.). In the case that you have only trivial symmetry, the matrix $R$ (if it exists) is uniquely determined by $X = RY$, thus these conditions might already determine a unique matrix...

Comment: @DirkLiebhold That's true, but I'm not sure how to make use of such conditions. If I have, say, 300 pairs $p_1, \dots, p_{300}$ of points separated by distance 0.4 in both $X$ and $Y$, I know $R$ has to permute these pairs somehow, so I have a constraint of the form $(Rp_1 = p_1) \vee (Rp_1 = p_2) \vee \cdots$. Taking the conjunction of many such constraints gives me what is essentially a large CNF-satisfiability problem.

Comment: You could first of all find the rotation transforming the centroid of $X$ to the centroid of $Y$. If $X'$ is the transformed of $X$, compute $d+1$ orthogonal principal axes of $X'$ and $Y$ and find the rotation taking every principal axis of $X'$ to the corresponding principal axis of $Y$.

Comment: @Aretino That's a great idea! I just took a year of mechanics -- can't believe I hadn't thought of the inertia matrix myself. The only problem is the possibility of degenerate eigenvalues, in which case there is a continuous family of principal axes to choose from. I expect many of my point sets to exhibit nearly-degenerate eigenvalues, and computing them to sufficient precision to distinguish true degeneracy from apparent degeneracy will be challenging.

Comment: Of course, if there are many symmetries you can have degenerate eigenvectors. That means that in the corresponding subspace several rotations could do the job. Picking corresponding points in the subspace, however, shouldn't be so difficult: you could for instance take points at the same distance from the subspace rotation center.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute inertia matrices $M_X$ and $M_Y$ with respect to coordinate origin in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$, whose components are:
$$
M_{X(ij)}=\sum_{x\in X}\big(|x|^2\delta_{ij}-x_ix_j\big),
\quad
M_{Y(ij)}=\sum_{y\in Y}\big(|y|^2\delta_{ij}-y_iy_j\big),
$$
and diagonalise them, to find two sets of orthogonal eigenvectors with their eigenvalues. If $X$ and $Y$ are isometric, then $M_X$ and $M_Y$ should have the same eigenvalues.

If that is the case, the rotation carrying each eigenvector of $M_X$ to the corresponding eigenvector of $M_Y$ should also carry each point of $X$ to a point of $Y$.