# Given two sets of points $A$ and $B$ in $\mathbb R^n$, is there an efficient way to tell if $B$ is just a rotation of $A$ about some fixed point?

Tags: geometry, computational-complexity

For two sets of points in $\mathbb R^n$, $A$ and $B$, is there an efficient way to determine if we can rotate $B$ onto $A$?

Edit: Thanks for all the comments!

I wanted to be as general as possible, but we can restrict $A$ and $B$ to be the extreme points of a convex $n$-polytope, changing the problem to polytope isomorphism. If you all think this is too big of a change in the spirit of the question, I'll make a new one

Also I do mean computable in polynomial time when I ask for efficiency. I'm optimistic that there's a solution that's based on |$A$| and is invariant to $n$

Comment: No, in general.

Comment: @Qurultay - can you cite where you are getting that answer, or at least explain it a bit better.

Comment: When we talk "efficiency" we probably mean some computational efficiency but then we are kind of out of luck when talking about $\mathbb{R}^n$. I wonder if there are any results regarding the computational complexity of determining whether two subsets of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ are a rotation of one another.

Comment: @Mason I agree. This is a computational complexity problelm. Surely there is a way if we exhaustively compare all combinations of points. Probably efficient means polynomial.

Comment: Well, first of all $A$ and $B$ must have same cardinality.

Comment: @Qurultay Ah... infinite sets I take it you're talking about. I think we can safely assume the OP meant finite sets. But it's a fair point.

Comment: Your question was asked [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/40246/complexity-of-testing-if-two-sets-of-m-points-in-mathbbrn-differ-only-by) and the answer seems to be "this is open"

Comment: @Mason Thanks for the link! I looked at the one you have now as well as the other one you had up and I got a little lost in the explanation of both. The cs post says that the problem remains open, but it felt like the math post was saying that you could use the inertia matrix to solve the problem. Is the only issue in this case a matter of time complexity?

Comment: Yes. The openness seems to be a matter of the time complexity. The link for the math related MSE question is [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353271/determine-if-one-point-set-is-a-rotation-of-another)